# android - pure service application

Tags: android, android-studio

Is it possible to write application which is a pure service, with no activity at all ?

This is becuase the application has no need to show any windows/gui.

I browsed some service samples, but they all contain activity (in AndroidManifest.xml), so I'm not sure, if that is possible.

EDIT:

I understand that a "service without activity" is not recommended. But still :

1. In case it is a pure service, is there a way to move the service from stopped state to active state.  ? How can I be sure that the service is not killed ?
2. In case I add some dummy activity (which does nothing!), can there still be a way to assure that the service will not be stopped ?

Thanks,
Ran

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to write application which is a pure service, with no activity at all

Only if you are planning on building your own custom ROM or have some other way to get the app moved out of the stopped state. Otherwise, your app will never run.

For normal apps, they are moved out of the stopped state when the user first starts up the launcher activity.

> This is becuase the application has no need to show and windows/gui.

Users will expect the ability to control how your service behaves. Lots of lawyers will expect the ability to see your terms of service, licenses for incorporated components, etc. And so on.

**UPDATE** based on revised question:

> Is there a way to move the service from stopped state to active state.

Have a launcher activity. Otherwise, there is no general-purpose way to do this.

> How can I be sure that the service is not killed ?

You don't. The user can do whatever the user wants, including terminating your process. Android will terminate your process as well, to free up system RAM for other apps.

Comment: "Only if you are planning on building your own custom ROM or have some other way to get the app moved out of the stopped state. ". Is there some simple way of making the service move out of stop state ? I will edit the question with this important comment. thx.